# Compiling Allegro 4.2 For MinGW/CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, mingw, allegro

I'm having trouble getting Allegro to Compile. When I begin the fix.bat mingw, it gives me an output which says:

```
Configuring for Windows/Allegro...Stop!
```

Yet, when I try to compile the rest by typing mingw32-make.exe, the following is output:

```
makefile.all:248: ***recipe commences before first target. Stop.
```

I've been spending a good hour trying to get this to compile, and there I haven't been able to find much on the net in terms of troubleshooting specifically for MinGW.

Everything I've done has been from [here](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Code%3a%3aBlocks), though nothing past the point of compilation.

If anyone would like a log file of some sort, please let me know how I can provide that and I will as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no reason to use Allegro 4.2 as it is past end of life. If you want to use the 4 series, you should be using the 4.4 branch.

http://www.allegro.cc/files/?v=4.4

It's possible that the Makefile on it will just work, but you may also need to update your copy of MinGW in case the version you have is buggy.

Also, there's not much use in compiling Allegro yourself unless you are planning on working on the library itself. The link above has binary downloads that include everything you need to use the library.

Comment: I wasn't aware there were binaries for the MinGW compiler. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question: how do I install the binary? If there's documentation anywhere, could you point me to it? I haven't been able to find anything for the 4 series.

Comment: All you need to do is extract it to a place like c:\allegro, and then add c:\allegro\include and c:\allegro\lib to your IDE's configuration. You can add c:\allegro\bin to your IDE's PATH variable if it has one, or to your system's global one.

Comment: Well, I updated my C:\MinGW\include, lib, and bin files by just copy/pasting the lib/include/bin folders from allegro to that. I then set my compiler directory of the code::blocks IDE I'm using to C:\MinGW. I also added the bin directory of my allegro folder to the system Path. Unfortunately, allegro_init() is considered still to be "undefined." Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't linking against Allegro. e.g., liballegro-4.4.2-md.a if you are using the binaries.